# Trying to pass ajax value from php to jquery in selectize

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, selectize.js

I am very new to jquery and ajax. Trying to implement selectize plugin that would query the database and return the values as dropdown. In order to do that, here is my php code that brings back data from the table. If I type the url for this php page and pass parameters, it brings back data in json format. {"movies":"value1"}{"movies":"value2"} .....

```
$q = $_GET['query'];
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
       die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT column_name from table where segment_name like '%$q%'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        error_reporting(0);

        $name->movies = "";
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
      while($segment_name = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

       $name->movies = $segment_name["segment_name"];
       $movies = json_encode($name);
       echo $movies;
       }
   } else {
   echo "0 results";
   }
   $conn->close();
```

And, here is the jQuery code from the selectize plugin.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js lt-ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Selectize.js Demo</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
        <!--[if IE 8]><script src="js/es5.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../dist/js/standalone/selectize.js"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        .selectize-control.movies .selectize-dropdown [data-selectable] {
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
            height: 60px;
            position: relative;
            -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
            box-sizing: content-box;
            padding: 10px 10px 10px 60px;
        }
        .selectize-control.movies .selectize-dropdown [data-selectable]:last-child {
            border-bottom: 0 none;
        }
        .selectize-control.movies .selectize-dropdown .by {
            font-size: 11px;
            opacity: 0.8;
        }
        .selectize-control.movies .selectize-dropdown .by::before {
            content: 'by ';
        }
        .selectize-control.movies .selectize-dropdown .name {
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }
        .selectize-control.movies .selectize-dropdown .description {
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #a0a0a0;
        }
        .selectize-control.movies .selectize-dropdown .actors,
        .selectize-control.movies .selectize-dropdown .description,
        .selectize-control.movies .selectize-dropdown .movies {
            display: block;
            white-space: nowrap;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
        }
        .selectize-control.movies .selectize-dropdown .actors {
            font-size: 10px;
            color: #a0a0a0;
        }
        .selectize-control.movies .selectize-dropdown .actors span {
            color: #606060;
        }
        .selectize-control.movies .selectize-dropdown img {
            height: 60px;
            left: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            border-radius: 3px;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
        }
        .selectize-control.movies .selectize-dropdown .meta {
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 10px;
        }
        .selectize-control.movies .selectize-dropdown .meta li {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            display: inline;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        .selectize-control.movies .selectize-dropdown .meta li span {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .selectize-control.movies::before {
            -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s;
            transition: opacity 0.2s;
            content: ' ';
            z-index: 2;
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            top: 12px;
            right: 34px;
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
            background: url(images/spinner.gif);
            background-size: 16px 16px;
            opacity: 0;
        }
        .selectize-control.movies.loading::before {
            opacity: 0.4;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <h1>Selectize.js</h1>
            <div class="demo">
                <h2>Loading from API</h2>
                <p>This demo shows how to integrate third-party data, loaded asynchronously.</p>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label for="select-movie">Movie:</label>
                    <select id="select-movie" class="movies" placeholder="Find a movie..."></select>
                </div>
                <script>
                // <select id="select-movie"></select>
                $('#select-movie').selectize({
                    valueField: 'movies',
                    labelField: 'movies',
                    searchField: 'movies',
                    options: [],
                    create: false,
                    render: {
                        option: function(item, escape) {
                                return '<div>' +
                                '<span class="movies">' +
                                    '<span class="name">' + escape(item.movies) + '</span>' +
                                '</span>' +
                            '</div>';
                        }
                    },
                    load: function(query, callback) {
                        if (!query.length) return callback();
                        $.ajax({
                            //url: 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.json',
                            url:'http://localhost/selectize/examples/myphp.php?query='+ encodeURIComponent(query),
                            type: 'GET',
                            dataType: 'jsonp',
                            data: {
                                q: query,
                                //page_limit: 10,
                                //apikey: '3qqmdwbuswut94jv4eua3j85'
                            },
                            error: function() {
                                callback();
                            },
                            success: function(res) {
                                console.log(res);
                                callback(res);
                                alert(res);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
                </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But, now I am lost as to how to make this work. I know I am a newbie so, asking for help.

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't see any errors in the html page. However, resources page show myphp.php with the data.

Comment: Please be more clear about what your expected outcome is. Maybe include a screenshot of your page and some comments about what is wrong.

Comment: My code doesn't do anything i.e. it doesn't open the dropdown or show any errors in the console. However, the original selectize code opens the dropdown and lists github repositories based on search criteria. (see Remote Source - Github or movie example) https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/

Comment: So, I was able to figure the issue. The issue was with the php script; it wasn't encoding the data correctly even though it seemed correct. Other than that, the selectize part is straight forward.